# How can I make my code New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11} be more better?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create one auto-generated id program. May I ask how I can let my program have more quality and I don't need to add the number one by one?

```
Private ids As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}

Private count As Integer = 0
```

Comment: First focus on making the question 'more quality' (no offence)

Comment: why ms-access tag?

Comment: Common mistake in thinking that an ID is a number. IDs are conceptual tokens *usually* best represented with a string. However, if you are using MS-Access, why not let it set the ID for you? If you need uniqueness, then come up with a simple system such as the time of registration (1907300620 - to the minute). The usual exception is when IDs double as something else (e.g. a membership number which is an outward facing token for identification).

Comment: @AJD " IDs are conceptual tokens usually best represented with a string" Interesting! When I see ID, I think of a sequential number (databases records). For strings I would think GUID.

Comment: @Mary - that is the point. You don't do anything with that number except use it to link to a record. The cardinality of the number means nothing and you don't do math on it. As such, it is not a number, just a token.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Enumerable.Range` to generate a list of integers between a minimum and maximum number. For example:

```
Dim ids As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit unclear, I believe you are asking "How to add numbers to list without doing it manually?"

Then you do the following:

```
Private ids As New List(Of Integer) 
For x=1 to 12
    ids.Add(x)
Next
```

Comment: Even tho the question is not clear, but it does mention 'auto generating ID'. ID's have to be random and unique.

Comment: @cruleD yes these is the question what would like to ask (without doing it manually?") but the code you provide for me it is no work on my program i get error on For x=1 to 12
    ids.Add(x)

Comment: @christing What kind of error? There should be no error.

Comment: @CruleD I bet, it is a "i is not declared".